# How to get the Selected Item from the default Context Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have searched everywhere looking for an answer to this question but found nothing. Everyone else seems to have a custom context menu and wants to get the selected item from there.

In my view class, I have several TextBoxes and they all have their default context menu containing 3 items: Cut, Copy and Paste.
Let' say tb is a TextBox, then tb has a ContextMenu property which has an Items property. I want to get the item selected by the user from this Items collection in a way so I can check if it was Cut, Copy or Paste:

```
var selectedItem = getSelectedItem(tb.ContextMenu.Items);
bool IsPaste = selectedItem == Paste; // Paste might be Items[2] but I'm not sure
```

Can anyone help me how to achieve something like that?

**Edited:** "getSelectedItem()" doesn't exist. The aswer to my question would be an implementation of that method.

Comment: and why is it not possible using commands ?

Comment: I'm new to wpf, can you please give me an example that works?

Comment: tell us your code and explain what you want to do ? I guess you want to know if user pressed paste ?

Comment: When you debug it, what is selectedItem ?

Comment: I want to know how do you get the user selection from the context menu in a general way when you have a regular textbox. Did he choose cut, copy or paste from the context menu? There should be an easy way of telling the user selection...

Comment: @Yagzii There's no method like getSelectedItem(). I just want to achieve something like that.

Comment: @tomsoos I have edited my answer. Try that..

Answer (score 0):

I think here you want to bind a command to your view ..

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
```

if not following command pattern you can user menu item click as well. in click handler you will know which menu item has been clicked and there you can make your code.

Comment: I have several textboxes on the UI and the user can also add more textboxes later by clicking on an Add button. I need a generic answer that can handle context menu item selection on any of these textboxes. I try to make it more understandable with a scenario: user adds a new textbox, clicks on it with the right button, cuts or copy-pastes something, then depending on his selection (cut or copy-paste) execute different code.

Comment: well you can reuse menuitems cant you ?

Comment: I'm really new to wpf so excuse my question but what do you mean by "reusing menuitems"? Also I would like to solve this using code behind and contextmenu does not have MenuItem property.

Comment: is this going to be a dynamic context menu or the items remain fairly common ?

Comment: The context menu is always the default context menu attached to any textbox and has 3 items: cut, copy and paste.

Comment: well then you can create one context menu and use it on all textboxes, and handle click handler once per contxtmenu item

Comment: So, there is no way to achieve that with the default context menu in .Net?

Answer (score -2):

You have to add a clickevent to your xml. Something like...

```
<MenuItem Header="Paste" InputGestureText="Ctrl+V" Click="Paste_Click" />

private void Paste_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: how is you code different from .. bool IsPaste = selectedItem == Paste; ?

Comment: That line would do exactly the same as my second line, it doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: shouldn't var selectedItem = getSelectedItem(tb.ContextMenu.Items); be var selectedItem = getSelectedItem(tb.SelectedItem) ?

Comment: @Yagzii There's no method like that. And I want to get the selected item from the context menu not from tb.

Comment: your edit is exactly what tomsoos is doing already, please make clear what you trying to say here.